# Turning vertical lines of code to horizontal in the editor

Tags: android-studio

I'm facing challenges while navigating through long code files in Android Studio. Scrolling through extensive code can be overwhelming, and I'm looking for efficient ways to manage and navigate my codebase. I've explored some basic shortcuts, such as collapsing/expanding code blocks and using the recent files popup, but I'm seeking more faster and way and more special on code that are not blocks.

is there a way to turn long list of vertical lines of code horizontal so that scrolling becomes easier.

I have tried

1. ctrl alt L
2. Folding
   I am not satisfied
   I want something like this

```
                 sp.getString("arrayNumber1", "4"),
                 sp.getString("arrayNumber2", "4"),
                 sp.getString("arrayNumber3", "4"),
                 sp.getString("arrayNumber4", "4"),
                 sp.getString("arrayNumber5", "4"),
                 sp.getString("arrayNumber6", "4"),
                 sp.getString("arrayNumber7", "4"),
                 sp.getString("arrayNumber8", "4"),
                 sp.getString("arrayNumber9", "4"),
                 sp.getString("arrayNumber10", "4"),
                 sp.getString("arrayNumber11", "4"),
```

to be like this with shortcut or something

```
 sp.getString("arrayNumber1", "4"), sp.getString("arrayNumber2", "4")
```